# Ammonite Ivy Import Fails For Joda Time

Tags: scala, ivy, read-eval-print-loop, ammonite

I have the following in my predef.sc file and when I load Ammonite via my terminal, it fails for one library, the joda-time:

```
import $ivy.`org.typelevel::cats-core:2.1.1`, cats._, cats.implicits._
import $ivy.`org.scalatest::scalatest:3.0.8`,org.scalatest._
import $ivy.`org.scalacheck::scalacheck:1.14.0`
import $ivy.`io.monix::monix:3.1.0`
import $ivy.`dev.zio::zio:1.0.0-RC18`
import $ivy.`com.github.nscala-time::nscala-time:2.26.0`
import $ivy.`org.typelevel::cats-effect:2.1.2`
import $ivy.`com.github.chocpanda::scalacheck-magnolia:0.3.1`
import $ivy.`io.chrisdavenport::cats-scalacheck:0.2.0`
import $ivy.`net.ruippeixotog::scala-scraper:2.2.0`
import $ivy.`com.softwaremill.sttp.client3::core:3.1.9`
import $ivy.`joda-time::joda-time:2.10.14`
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.concurrent.Await
import monix.eval.Task
import org.scalacheck.{Arbitrary, Gen}
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.DateTime
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.DateTimeFormat
import org.scalacheck.magnolia._
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.browser.JsoupBrowser
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.DSL._
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.DSL.Extract._
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.DSL.Parse._
import sttp.client3._
import monix.reactive.Observable
import monix.execution.Ack.Continue
import monix.execution.{Ack, Scheduler}
import monix.reactive.observers.Subscriber
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, Days, Interval, Weeks}
import scala.math.Integral.Implicits._
```

The actual error message:

```
joesan@joesan-S-14-v5:~$ amm
Loading...
Failed to resolve ivy dependencies:Error downloading joda-time:joda-time_2.13:2.10.14
  not found: /home/joesan/.ivy2/local/joda-time/joda-time_2.13/2.10.14/ivys/ivy.xml
  not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time_2.13/2.10.14/joda-time_2.13-2.10.14.pom
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved by adding a dependency to the nscala-time as below:

```
import $ivy.`com.github.nscala-time::nscala-time:2.30.0`
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
```

Not sure why this was able to resolve while the joda-time not!